# Unsatisfied dependency spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Just finished creating entity, repo, service and controller for table countries in db. I will attach everything here and error which I have after trying to run test file.

CountriesEntity.java:

```
 package com.example.ProjekatFakture.country;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "countries", schema = "fakture", catalog = "")
public class CountriesEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cou_id")
    private int couId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    public int getCouId() {
        return couId;
    }

    public void setCouId(int couId) {
        this.couId = couId;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CountriesEntity that = (CountriesEntity) o;

        if (couId != that.couId) return false;
        if (code != null ? !code.equals(that.code) : that.code != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (fullName != null ? !fullName.equals(that.fullName) : that.fullName != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = couId;
        result = 31 * result + (code != null ? code.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (fullName != null ? fullName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

CountryRepository.java:

```
package com.example.ProjekatFakture.country;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<CountriesEntity, Integer> {
}
```

CountryService.java:

```
package com.example.ProjekatFakture.country;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CountryService {
    private final CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryService(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    public CountriesEntity saveCountry(CountriesEntity country){
        return countryRepository.save(country);
    }
}
```

CountryController.java:

```
package com.example.ProjekatFakture.country;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@Controller
public class CountryController {

    private final CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    public CountryController(CountryService countryService) {
        this.countryService = countryService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public CountriesEntity createCountry(@RequestBody CountriesEntity country){
        return countryService.saveCountry(country);
    }
}
```

And test java file:

```
package com.example.ProjekatFakture;

import com.example.ProjekatFakture.country.CountriesEntity;
import com.example.ProjekatFakture.country.CountryService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringJUnitConfig
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class CountryServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Test
    public void testCreateCountry(){

        CountriesEntity country = new CountriesEntity();
        country.setName("Srbija");
        country.setCode("SRB");
        country.setFullName("Republic of Serbia");

        CountriesEntity createdCountry = countryService.saveCountry(country);

        assertNotNull(createdCountry);
        assertNotNull(createdCountry.getCouId());
        assertEquals("Srbija", createdCountry.getName());
        assertEquals("SRB", createdCountry.getCode());
        assertEquals("Republic of Serbia", createdCountry.getFullName());
    }
}
```

Here is error which I receive after trying to run that test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.ProjekatFakture.CountryServiceTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'countryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.ProjekatFakture.country.CountryService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:417)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.ProjekatFakture.country.CountryService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 76 more
```

Have you guys ever faced something like this and where I am mistaken?

Comment: First of all: Take care of java naming conventions. package name should be lower case

Comment: @Jens fixed that, from ProjekatFakture to fakture. Thanks for advice

Comment: Wild guess using Spring Boot 3.x? Next to that you are using `@DataJpaTest` which will only load persistence related things **not** services, controllers etc. etc. so trying to inject a service in an `@DataJpaTest` will fail. The `@DataJpaTest` is meant to test repositories.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am avoiding to use it in any 3.x version because of lot of issues which I had, its about 2.7.x something, not sure but can't find where to check that but pretty sure I set that up on 2.7.x

Comment: As stated (as well) you are using `@DataJpaTest` which will only setup JPA and repositories and will ignore everything else. Injecting a service will fail.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes, that was the reason. I have changed @ DataJpaTest to @ SpringBootTest and put @ Autowired annotation over service instance in test. It did insertion in my db. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.fakture;

import com.example.fakture.country.CountriesEntity;
import com.example.fakture.country.CountryService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringJUnitConfig
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class CountryServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Test
    public void testCreateCountry(){

        CountriesEntity country = new CountriesEntity();
        country.setName("Srbija");
        country.setCode("SRB");
        country.setFullName("Republic of Serbia");

        CountriesEntity createdCountry = countryService.saveCountry(country);

        assertNotNull(createdCountry);
        assertNotNull(createdCountry.getCouId());
        assertEquals("Srbija", createdCountry.getName());
        assertEquals("SRB", createdCountry.getCode());
        assertEquals("Republic of Serbia", createdCountry.getFullName());
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).